# how to create login-signup and main app separately in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, multi-page-application

I just learned angular. I know about app-routing, and also heard about lazy loading and multi-project workspace in angular.
I want to make a web app that has this functionality-

When a user visits the webpage, the "welcome" application is loaded, with routes login, signup, and pricing.
After the user finished with the login-signup thing, the main application should load with its own route.
How can I achieve this functionality? I am confused

Comment: you can use route guards to check for user authentication and on successful login redirect to main application.

Answer (score 0):

This is angular is called `lazy loading` with `feature modules`, You can read the  documentation with practical examples [here](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules)